How do interfaces solve the circle-ellipse problem?
It is sometimes said that interfaces solve several problems of object-oriented programming, in particular the circle-ellipse problem. It would be this interface
class IEllipse {
public:
  virtual double GetXRadius() const = 0;
  virtual double GetYRadius() const = 0;
  virtual void SetXRadius(double r) = 0;
  virtual void SetYRadius(double r) = 0;
} 

But then we'd still have this kind of problematic function, that works for some implementations of IEllipse, but not for the circle implementation (that plugs both SetXRadius and SetYRadius to the same storage variable radius):
std::string SerializeDestructively(IEllipse& ellipse) {
  std::stringstream s;
  s << ellipse.GetXRadius() << " ";
  ellipse.SetXRadius(0.0);
  s << ellipse.GetYRadius();
  ellipse.SetYRadius(0.0);
  return s.str();
}

It seems the problem is rather that IEllipse represents a resizable ellispe, in each dimension. The circle does not implement that interface, because when flattened, it is no longer a circle. And writing the definition of an ellipse in an interface does not solve that.

An ellipse in general is not a circle, as such one should not inherit from the other.  (An ellipse is a circle in a specific degenerate case, but not in the general case, and the invariants of circle are not the invariants of an ellipse.)

Do you really want inheritance?

@Jarod42 I heard that implementing interfaces is better than class inheritance (Java has different syntaxes for these 2 mechanisms for instance). I wonder exactly how interfaces are better, in particular for solving the circle-ellipse problem.

@Eljay A subtype is never in general its supertype. If it was it would be a type isomorphism, not a subtype. The question is how interfaces better represent subtyping than class inheritance.

Re. "I heard that implementing interfaces is better than class inheritance": please provide a specific reference (the link you provide is rather vague and wide ranging).  Also, C++ has no formal definition of an 'interface' so if by interface you mean a class comprising nothing but pure virtual members then you should state that.

@G.M. I litterally heard it from some of my colleagues, so I don't have URLs :-) However I do see Java and C# have different syntaxes for interfaces and classes, and I think Go banned class inheritance.

Java and C# separates interfaces and classes because they only support multiple inheritance from interfaces. C++ does not have this separation at the language level. Both side will of course argue that their choice "is better".

You should overload operator<< for your IEllipse class.

Real life, ahem, circles and ellipses don't change their sizes. Remove the setters, and the problem disappears in a puff of logic. Circle returns to be a kind of ellipse, and everything is fine and well in the Liskov Substitution Land again. Setters are not your friends anyway, for various reasons. Use immutable objects as much ans you can.

IMO the Circle-Elipse problem is an good example where inheritance based polymorphism isn't a good solution. Which is ironic because it is almost always used in inheritance based polymorphism tutorials.

I meant do you really want to have a ICircle? bool IElipse::isCircle() const might make more sense. In the same way, you don't create an IElipse_5x_4y for specific size.

Re: "Java and C# have different syntaxes for interfaces and classes," but that may be considered a mistake.

Interfaces do not solve the circle-ellipse problem and cannot solve the problem, at least if you're trying to also maintain the mathematical properties of each shape.  The reason this problem is used is because it's a good example of a mathematical concept (a circle is a special kind of ellipse) not working with proper inheritance (i.e., the Liskov substitution principle).
Here's a silly example that shows the problem:
void makeTallAndSkinny(IEllipse &e) {
    auto const oldX = e.GetXRadius();
    auto const oldY = e.GetYRadius();
    e.SetYRadius(oldY * 2);
    e.SetXRadius(oldX * 0.5);
}

The only way an interface would work is if you break the contract of IEllipse to the point where SetXRadius and SetYRadius are effectively meaningless.  In fairness you could also break the concept of Circle to the point where it's also meaningless (at least compared to the mathematical notion of a circle), but you're still breaking something.
This is also true if your Mammal interface assumes GivesLiveBirth() == true and you have Platypus modeled as a Mammal.  Just because a relationship matches your mental model doesn't mean it fits with interfaces and object-oriented programming.
What you could do in C++ is have Circle leverage private inheritance.  That would let Circle and friends use it as an IEllipse where appropriate, in cases where they knew the interface may not perfectly hold but it's safe (e.g., not my example above).  Generic code wouldn't be able to pass a Circle though, which maintains the type model your program depends on it.

This is the first time I see a meaningful example of private inheritance, thanks

I'm not convinced this "problem" is real. It is a failure of imagination rather than anything else. Thinking in X-Y coordinates limits your options. Specifying the (two) foci of the ellipse and its average radius allows a perfectly smooth transition between both forms (both foci are the same for a circle). If you insist on thinking in X-Y you also have to have an angle to make the semi major and minor axes of the ellipse match with reality.  It is GetXRadius() and GetYRadius() that are conceptually flawed!

@MartinBrown - It's been about 25 years since I took geometry, so I'll defer to you on foci.  However, that implementation still fails to provide proper inheritance if the base class permits the foci to be manipulated independently and a Circle requires foci1 == foci2.

@MartinBrown - If you still don't think the problem is real, I strongly suggest you read everything here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/proper-inheritance#circle-ellipse.  it explains the problem in far better detail than I do and includes a discussion on proper inheritance.  The latter is useful as it applies to all languages with OO functionality, not just C++.

The point of an interface is to decouple the behaviors of an object from the actual implementation.  There's nothing wrong with am object having multiple interfaces if it makes sense.  Microsoft's COM model assumes this will be quite common, and gives you a way to ask for an interface from an object if you already have a pointer to one of its other interfaces (see IUnknown::QueryInterface).
class IEllipse {
public:
  virtual double GetXRadius() const = 0;
  virtual double GetYRadius() const = 0;
  virtual void SetXRadius(double r) = 0;
  virtual void SetYRadius(double r) = 0;
};

class ICircle {
public:
  virtual double GetRadius() const = 0;
  virtual void SetRadius(double r) = 0;
};

class ConcreteEllipse: public ICircle, IEllipse
{
  ICircle * GetCircleInterface() { return this; }
  IEllipse * GetEllipseInterface() { return this; }
};

